# Загрузка картинок и создание cookie

Tags: flash, php, html, javascript

Привет! Использую загрузчик файлов swfupload и у меня встала такая задача:
нужно загрузить изображение (-я) и сохранить их ссылки в куки, при этом я заметил интересную вещь: при загрузке к примеру 4х картинок, запросов на файл upload.php будет ровно 4, т.к при загрузке каждой картинки идет запрос на upload.php. Если просто юзать setcookie('image',$filename) то в куки будет записываться только последняя картинка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вся работа с куками на стороне сервера
2. swfupload — использует flash, а он всегда передает куки от IE,  независимо от браузера, поэтому нужно их дублировать
3. setcookie('image',$filename) — заменяет текущую, а не устанавливает ещё одну

P.S. А зачем вы вообще передаете название файла через куки? Это какое-то крайне стремное решение.

Comment: Знаю, но другого решения я увы, не придумал. Храню их в куки для того, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку "Добавить товар" эти куки в обработчик add_product.php, а затем записать их в базу.
Если есть идеи - выслушаю, буду благодарен если еще и решение подгоните ;)

Comment: Чтобы помочь вам, нужно хотя бы знать, как связана загрузка файлов с "Добавить товар". Если бы мне нужно было запоминать какие-то действия юзера, то я бы их складывал в сессию/memcached/в таблицу для временных данных/тупо в файл/и т.п.

Comment: Есть вкладка "Добавить товар". Это и есть интерфейс добавления товара, в ней есть формы типа "Название товара" и т.п., так же есть форма добавления картинок в галерею, вот собсно и вопрос: как лучше загружать и хранить данные картинки? После нажатия на кнопку "Добавить товар" идет пост-запрос на add_product.php, где и происходит вся логика добавления, там я и планировал выдирать значения из куки и уже вставлять ссылки на картинки в БД, а в галереи тупо выводить их.

Comment: Если по хорошему, то: При загрузке, файлы кладутся в табличку Files и в ответ возвращаем уникальный идентификатор записи о файле, который добавляем в форму "Добавления товара", например <input type="hidden" name="files[]" value="{{$UNIQ_FILE_ID}}"/>. После того, как юзер нажал на "Добавить товар", добавляем запись в табличку Products, получаем уникальный идентификатор записи и связываем id загруженных файлов с продуктом, при помощи третьей таблички ProductFiles, у которой есть поля product_id и file_id. Вот и всё.